# Cross-validation for time-series

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using Timeseriessplit function from sklearn, to create train and test sets
for the cross-validation of a timeseries. The idea is for instance to use the n-1 datapoints for training, and the n-th datapoint for testing. This split must be always ordered, as it is a timeseries.
However, I don't understand, why the dataset X in the example is formatted as follows:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)
print(tscv)  
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

what is the logic behind a preperation of the data as X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])?
And of course I read the notes on the page, but still not understanding

Comment: Can you try to be more specific in what you exactly don't understand on X array structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in time series data you want to predict `y[t]` based on `X[0:t-1]` data. This `sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit` method seems to take as arguments a single complete timeseries `X` of size `N` (where `N` is the number of instances at different times steps) and its corresponding labels at each time steps `y`. Then, `X` shape is (4,2) because we have four instance at different time steps and each instance have 2 features.

How we interpret this two features might be controversial:

1. We can consider each instance to be a single sample in an specific point in time having a set of features. Or...
2. We can consider each instance to be a set of points in time, defining the instance itself during a time interval.

Both option seem correct to me. Although how we may interpret the structure of `X`, the matter here is how `TimeSeriesSplit` splits the data avoiding testing data instance from previous time steps of training data instances.

Comment: So, the last [3,4] does not necessarily reflect the first [3,4], i.e. what we have is more like: ([Timepoint1_Day1, Timepoint2_Day1], [Timepoint1_Day2, Timepoint2_Day2], [[Timepoint1_Day3, Timepoint2_Day3]], [[Timepoint1_Day4, Timepoint2_Day4]])? I am just wondering if I have my timerseries which is one array, do I have to split it to pass it over to this function?

Comment: Hi again @TestGuest. I have been thinking on your question and considered that my previous answer was partial and incomplete, what can be misleading.  I have edited it, so please check it again!

Comment: Regarding your comment questions. It does not necessarily have your proposed structure ([Timepoint1_Day1, Timepoint2_Day1], [Timepoint1_Day2, Timepoint2_Day2], [[Timepoint1_Day3, Timepoint2_Day3]], [[Timepoint1_Day4, Timepoint2_Day4]]), check my new extended answer. --- Regarding your second question, You do not necessarily need to split your long one array timeseries data.  If you explain your concrete problem I might try to help you with what I would do (split or not split data before passing through the function).